# Will excessive commenting of code slow execution?

Tags: python, performance, comments, code-formatting, technical-debt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do comments slow down an interpreted language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731022/do-comments-slow-down-an-interpreted-language)

Will there be noticeable performance degradation in the execution of a large .py file if more than 75% of the lines of code are properly commented?

Comment: No, but if you have comments on 75% of your code, you may benefit from not commenting so much and rather writing readable code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No

When you run python, the first step is to convert to bytecode, which is what those `.pyc` files are. Comments are removed from these, so it won't matter<sup>*</sup>.

If you run with the `-O` or `-OO` option, python will produce "optimized" `pyo` files, which are negligibly faster, if faster at all. The main difference is that:

- with `-O` assertion are removed,
- with the `-OO` option, the `__doc__` strings are stripped out. Given that those are sometimes needed, running with `-OO` isn't recommended.

---

<sup>*</sup> it's been pointed out below that `.pyc` files are only saved for modules. Thus the top-level executable must be recompiled every time it's run. This step *could* slow down a *massive* python executable. In practice, most of the code should reside in modules, making this a non-issue.

Comment: ...so it could impact your *startup* time, but not your long term execution time.  In particular, if everything is precompiled into `.pyc` files, this is a *one time* cost, not a per-run cost.

Comment: I doubt it will impact the startup time noticeably, since Python simply ignores anything between a # and a newline.  Also, the .pyc files are preserved between runs if the .py file is not modified, so any effect is only for the first time the program is run.

Comment: -1, since only imported modules are compiled to .pyc; executed scripts are not.

Comment: @Wooble, good point, but I've never noticed the effect. The only scenarios I can think of where this would matter are when you're running a _very_ long strip or where you're making repeated calls to a python executable from outside python. In practice I've never run into either.

Comment: @Wooble if you're following best-practices, your scripts are only thin wrappers around modules; setuptools and kin will even generate these wrappers for you automatically.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: maybe so, but OP speaks of "execution of a large .py file". Of course the comments will only affect startup time, but it will be every time the large script is run, because a .pyc file won't be created. The "No" part is correctish, but the explanation is misleading.

Comment: Even if you have a large, monolithic `.py` file invoked directly from the command line, it's trivial to write a "wrapper" for it that simply imports the big script. Then the big script gets compiled to a `.pyc` and only the one-line wrapper is parsed each time it's run.

Comment: More nitpicking: `-O` removes assertions and sets `__debug__ = False`, but it does not remove docstrings, only `-OO` does that. Running with `-O` is thus only harmful when you're debugging (or misusing assertions, which some codebases do).

Comment: @delnan thanks for pointing this out. I've added to my answer.