# Do comments slow down R?

Tags: r

Do comments slow down `R`?

This question has been asked twice on StackOverflow regarding python:

[Do comments slow down an interpreted language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731022/do-comments-slow-down-an-interpreted-language)
[Will excessive commenting of code slow execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486666/will-excessive-commenting-of-code-slow-execution)

For `python` the answer appears to be 'no'.  I do not know enough about the differences between the two languages to know how relevant those answers are for `R`.

Here is a similar question about white space in `R`.  Again the answer appears to be 'no'.

[does white space slow down processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368168/does-white-space-slow-down-processing)

Answer (score 6):

For R the answer appears to be 'yes', unless I made a mistake somewhere below.

```
# Time difference of 21.84725 secs
# Time difference of 24.05738 secs

# total.time.2 - total.time.1
#
# Time difference of 2.210126 secs

n <- 280

start.time.1 <- Sys.time()

b <- 2

for(i in 1:n) {
     for(j in 1:n) {
          for(k in 1:n) {

               b <- b + 2 - 1 - 0.75

          }
     }
}

b

end.time.1 <- Sys.time()

total.time.1 <- end.time.1 - start.time.1
total.time.1


start.time.2 <- Sys.time()

b <- 2

# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.


for(i in 1:n) {

# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.

     for(j in 1:n) {

# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.

          for(k in 1:n) {

# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.

               b <- b + 2 - 1 - 0.75

# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.
# I wonder whether comments slow down R.  Here are some comments.  Let's see.

          }
     }
}

b

end.time.2 <- Sys.time()

total.time.2 <- end.time.2 - start.time.2

total.time.1
total.time.2

total.time.2 - total.time.1
```

Comment: yes, indeed for example when creating a package, R removes all comments.This is why I've never seen a function inside R (eg giving `ls` to prompt) that has a line of comment.