# Squaring numbers in a loop

Tags: python

I have this python problem:

> Write a program that asks the user for a limit, and then prints out
>   the sequence of square numbers that are less than or equal to the
>   limit provided.
>
> Max: 10
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> 9 ​
>
> Here the last number is 9 because the next square number (16) would be
>   greater than the limit (10).
>
> Here is another example where the maximum is a square number:
>
> Max: 100  1
>
> 4
>
> 9
>
> 16
>
> 25
>
> 36
>
> 49
>
> 64
>
> 81
>
> 100

But I don't exactly know how to do this. So far I have

```
maximum = int(input("Max: "))

for i in range(1, maximum):
```

But don't really know how to process the numbers  and squaring them.

Thanks

Edit: I have

```
maximum = int(input("Max: "))

for i in range(1, maximum):
  if i*i <= maximum:
    print(i*i)
```

Comment: Hint: `i*i` is the square of `i`

Comment: You don't need a nested loop, just the `for` loop. What you want inside is an `if` statement. `if i*i > maximum…` then what? What do you when `maximum` is `10`, but `i*i` is 16? You `break` out of the loop, because you're done.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make it so when I enter '1' as the max, it  prints 1? Because currently when I type 1 nothing shows

Comment: got it nevermind thank you. I had to use  `for i in range(1, maximum + 1):`

Comment: @HollyM Please consider to [accept at least one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to post the answer that works. Thanks all for the help.

```
maximum = int(input("Max: "))

for i in range(1, maximum + 1):
  if i*i <= maximum:
    print(i*i)
```

Comment: this indeed works, but is highly inefficient. For example say you have maximum=10000, you loop over 10k numbers, but you should ideally do over 100.

Comment: It just works for the task I was doing, and the task didn't say anything about bigger numbers but thanks.

Comment: Just adding `else:` `break` will solve that performance problem, without making it significantly harder to understand.

Comment: Or just `range(1, int(math.sqrt(maximum))+1)` - seems equally understandable.

Answer (score 4):

```
'''
Ask the user input a limit and
convert input string into integer value
'''
limit = int(input("Please input the limit: "))

'''
Extract the squre root of `limit`.
In this way we discard every number (i) in range [0, limit]
whose square number ( i * i ) is not in range [0, limit].
This step improves the efficiency of your program.
'''
limit = int(limit ** .5)

'''
`range(a, b)` defines a range of [a, b)
In order to exclude zero,
we assign `a = 1`;
in order to include `limit`,
we assign `b = limit + 1`;

thus we use `range(1, limit + 1)`.
'''
for i in range(1, limit + 1):
    print(i * i)
```

Comment: This answer is good, but in general it is clearer to have the explanations in the comments as text.

Comment: I can't help but wonder: Will it (having explanations in texts) bring about performance burden in larger projects?

Comment: Comments bringing performance burden is not common. I'm suggesting this for readability, not for performance

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, your comment got e thinking, I searched and got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486666/will-excessive-commenting-of-code-slow-execution. Do you have some source where it provides some timing stats in highly commented v/s non commented code.

Comment: @DeepakSaini Once the code is compiled, the comments don't exist. For a module, it's pretty easy to test the difference in compile time; for a top-level script it's a bit more annoying. But in real life, it's almost never going to make a difference—if you're compiling the same code a million times, you've done something very wrong; normally you compile once per edit during development, then once per install, and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

I think a while loop may be better suited for this problem.

```
maximum = int(input("Max: "))

i = 1
while(i*i <= maximum):
   print(i*i) 
   i+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a few good, detailed answers.

But let's also have some fun, here is a one-line solution:

```
print(*(x**2 for x in range(1, 1 + int(int(input('Limit: '))**(1/2)))))
```

Comment: Nice, you even crammed the `input` in there. Well, maybe not _nice_, but… you know what I mean.

Comment: @abarnert If you appreciate how the input in *crammed in*, have a look at that one: `print(*takewhile(lambda x, i=int(input('Limit: ')): x <= i, map(lambda x: x*x, count())))` I know you like `itertools`.

Comment: Yeah, after reading your answer, I thought about cramming the input into my itertools answer exactly that way, except with `lambda x, *, _i=…` to make it clear that I was using the "default value as local" idiom instead of just golfing. But then I realized that really, I was just golfing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

First, the simplest change to your existing code is to get rid of that nested loop. Just have the `for` loop and an `if`:

```
for i in range(1, maximum+1):
    if i*i > maximum:
        break
    print(i*i)
```

Or just have the `while` loop and increment manually:

```
i = 1
while i*i <= maximum:
    print(i*i)
    i += 1
```

One thing: Notice I used `range(1, maximum+1)`? Ranges are half-open: `range(1, maximum)` gives us all the numbers up to but not including `maximum`, and we need to include `maximum` itself to have all the numbers up to `maximum` squared, in case it's 1. (That's the same reason to use `<=` instead of `<` in the `while` version.

---

But let’s have a bit more fun. If you had all of the natural numbers:

```
numbers = itertools.count(1)
```

… you could turn that into all of the squares:

```
squares = (i*i for i in numbers)
```

Don’t worry about the fact that there are an infinite number of them; we’re computing them lazily, and we’re going to stop once we pass `maximum`:

```
smallsquares = itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n<=maximum, squares)
```

… and now we have a nice finite sequence that we can just print out:

```
print(*smallsquares)
```

Or, if you’d prefer if all on one line (in which case you probably also prefer a `from itertools import count, takewhile`):

```
print(*takewhile(lambda n: n<=maximum, (i*i for i in count(1)))
```

But really, that lambda expression is kind of ugly; maybe (with `from functools import partial` and `from operator import ge`) it’s more readable like this:

```
print(*takewhile(partial(ge, maximum), (i*i for i in count(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**THE BELOW PROGRAM IS TO FIND SQUARE VALUE OF GIVE NUMBERS**

1. Enter the value you want to find.(Give a range)
2. the value you give runs and goes to r command.
3. i have used for loop in this case.
4. output will be displayed

## give the input

maximum = input("Enter Max: ")

r = range(1, maximum)

Square = maximum * maximum

## Execute THE loop

for i in r:

if i * i <= Square:

```
  print (i * i),
```

Comment: Hi Sudarshan G, welcome. Please consider adding more information.